# How do I add one more minute to my timer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer, countdowntimer

[Picture Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkOiR.png)

I need help adding one more minute using the on click button in Android Studio

Here's some of my timer code:

```
private void startTimer() {
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimerRunning = false;
            btnTest.setText("Start");
        }
    }.start();
    mTimerRunning = true;
    btnTest.setText("Pause");
}
private void pauseTimer() {
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    mTimerRunning = false;
    btnTest.setText("Start");
}
private void updateCountDownText() {
    int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
    String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    textViewShowTime.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    mProgressBar.setProgress((int)(mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this class does not have such a feature.

you can save the count of the button click, then create a new `CountDownTimer` with the timeout that you want. and you need to consider the remaining time in the `onTick` method.

You can create `CustomCountDowntimer` that extends from `CountDownTimer`. And do the things described above there.

see this [link](https://github.com/sm-jalali-f/CustomCountDownTimer)